# Need help identifying smd capacitor value

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, surface-mount

I have a samson auro x12D powered speaker and I cannot find a schematic or service manual anywhere on the internet for this board.

I identified 2 open capacitors (c10 c11) on the power board but I need some help figuring out what the values should be for replacements.

U2 is [NCP1271](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/ncp1271-d.pdf)

Is it safe to assume that c13 and c10 are the same value?
[image]

Comment: What did you use to determine the two caps were "open" ?  If you could trace the circuit a bit to determine the connection layout of the two caps you may be able to get a better answer.  In the mean time I linked the datasheet to your chip p/n, review the example circuit (on p18) for hints to typical component values.

Comment: Capacitors will normally show "open" when measured with an ohmmeter, unless there is something else in parallel with them to pass the ohmmeter's current.

Comment: @PeterBennett I used an ESR meter and they show overflow both on circuit and after removed from circuit

Comment: @nedd thanks I will check page 18. I didn't realize they had an example circuit in there. This is very helpful.